# Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'roundCorners'

Tags: ios, swift

Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'roundCorners'

```
cardView = UIView()
cardView.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.colorOptimusThree
cardView.roundCorners(cornerRadius: 4.0)
view.addSubview(cardView)
```

Comment: there is no method for UIView called "roundCorners".

Comment: It's probably an extension that you saw being used somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one..

```
 cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
 cardView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
 cardView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

UIView has a property called `layer` which has `cornerRadius` which you can use , so you have to use `cardView.layer.cornerRadius = "your float value"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extensions or just below your any view.

Below View

```
 cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
 cardView.layer.borderWidth = 2
 cardView.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

Extension

```
extension UIView {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat = 1) {
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

You can use extension Method by calling like this

```
cardView.cornerRadius(5, borderWidth: 1)
```

You'll see 2 method. First one without borderWidth and other with borderWidth.
If you want to be width 1 then you can ignore second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIView {
    func makeRoundedCorners(cornerRadius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat, masksToBounds: Bool) {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.masksToBounds = masksToBounds
    }
}
```